# how to fix incompatible foreign key constraints spring boot

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I have a spring boot application where I have two entities in a relationship. MeetingsSetting and meetingTime. One MeetingSetting can have multiple meetingTimes and one meetingtime belongs to one Meetingsetting.

I generate the databases through sql script and reference the foreing key their for the meetingTime entity. But I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Referencing column 'meeting_name' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg' are incompatible.
```

THe funny thing is I am not referencing the id anywhere not in my entity nor in my script. This is how my entity and script looks like:

meetingSetting:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Data

public class MeetingsSetting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meeting_Name", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingTime:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Data
public class MeetingTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name",insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private String meetingName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name", nullable = false)
    private MeetingsSetting meeting_Name;
}
```

and this is my script where I generate my tables:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table meeting_settings
(
    id           bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    meeting_name varchar(255) null,
    meeting_pw   varchar(255) null,
    meeting_url  varchar(255) null
);

create table meeting_times
(
    id                  bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    meeting_date        varchar(255) null,
    start_time          varchar(255) null,
    end_time            varchar(255) null,
    meeting_name        varchar(255) null,
    constraint fk_meeting_times_meeting_name
        foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_settings (meeting_name)
);
```

What could cause such an error? because I am not referencing anywhere the id.

UPDATE:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coorporate_blinddate?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=../generate.sql
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Test1234@@1&
server.port=8081
```

Hibernate Sequence:

```
Hibernate: create table meeting_settings (id bigint not null auto_increment, meeting_name varchar(255), meeting_pw varchar(255), meeting_url varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table meeting_settings_meeting_time (meetings_setting_id bigint not null, meeting_name bigint not null, primary key (meetings_setting_id, meeting_name)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table meeting_times (id bigint not null auto_increment, meeting_date varchar(255), end_time varchar(255), meeting_name varchar(255), start_time varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table meeting_settings drop index UK_klg4vqmhi7o9qff83ymly598o
Hibernate: alter table meeting_settings add constraint UK_klg4vqmhi7o9qff83ymly598o unique (meeting_name)
Hibernate: alter table meeting_settings_meeting_time drop index UK_jsn83wsxfkpm1xfencvsdkqj1
Hibernate: alter table meeting_settings_meeting_time add constraint UK_jsn83wsxfkpm1xfencvsdkqj1 unique (meeting_name)
Hibernate: alter table meeting_settings_meeting_time add constraint FK9lq62drkkslq6x381b3lieruu foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_times (id)
Hibernate: alter table meeting_settings_meeting_time add constraint FKglhgb5vgsviqm7t6vtmdx5e7t foreign key (meetings_setting_id) references meeting_settings (id)
Hibernate: alter table meeting_times add constraint FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_settings (id)
```

A table which is generated

```
meeting_settings_meeting_time
meetings_setting_id
meeting_name
PRIMARY
UK_jsn83wsxfkpm1xfencvsdkqj1
FK9lq62drkkslq6x381b3lieruu
FKglhgb5vgsviqm7t6vtmdx5e7t
UK_jsn83wsxfkpm1xfencvsdkqj1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `meeting_name` column is not unique in order to do the relationship you have done. Add `unique = true`

```
@Column(name = "meeting_name", unique = true)
private String meetingName;
```

And

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="meeting_name"))
private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I tried it in meetingSettings and meetingTime but still get the same error. With the Id reference

Comment: @haso I updated my answer, you can JoinTable to say it that is my join column.

Comment: THanks for the answer but now there is another error. I think I am going crazy haha.
Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like JoinTable or JoinColumn: com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.meetinsSetting.MeetingsSetting.meetingTime

Comment: If I take out the mappedBy part the old error comes again...with id

Comment: I found these two in the log:
Error executing DDL "alter table meeting_times drop foreign key FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg" via JDBC Statement

Table 'coorporate_blinddate.meeting_settings_meeting_time' doesn't exist

I was droping the table always before starting the application. Was this the error?

Comment: These two came alongside my old error when I delete mappedBy

Comment: I added my application.properties maybe the error is there

Comment: FOr some reason this Hibernate sequence is in the logs:
Hibernate: alter table meeting_times add constraint FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_settings (id)

Comment: @haso sorry, I forgot to remove mappedBy so, I updated my answer `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: Hi,
I had already tried that without mappedBy but it still not working... These two errors are coming:
Error executing DDL "alter table meeting_times add constraint FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_settings (id)" via JDBC Statement


Referencing column 'meeting_name' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg' are incompatible.

I even reinstalled mysql thinking it was an error caused by faulty installation but still no help

Comment: I added the table and new information which are generated and used

Comment: HI,
I could fix the error When I removed meetingName as a column from meetingTImes then it was added as a fk in that table. But Know I am getting an error when I try to save an object